# Android Unity Proguard config

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, proguard

I'm want obfuscate my android application with Unity library's(jar + native lib's). And i'm create Proguard config:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontwarn android.support.**
-verbose

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-libraryjars /libs/unity-classes.jar
-keep  class com.unity3d.** { *; }
-keep  class org.fmod.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers   class com.tms.rarus.videoserver.* { *; }
-keepclassmembers   class com.unity3d.player.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers   class org.fmod.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

When i'm try start Application with proguard obfusctae, i'm get next error log:

```
02-06 11:44:56.538: D/dalvikvm(13604): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.unity.game-1/libmain.so 0x41b78330
02-06 11:44:56.538: D/dalvikvm(13604): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.unity.game-1/libmain.so 0x41b78330
02-06 11:44:56.554: E/Unity(13604): Unable to locate player settings. caused by: org.e.a.b: resource not found: /META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory make sure that parser implementing XmlPull API is available
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeVideoFrameCallback:VILII
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSoftInputClosed:V
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetTouchDeltaY:VF
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetInputString:VL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetInputCanceled:VZ
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetExtras:VL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetDefaultDisplay:VI
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeResume:V
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeResize:VIIII
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeRequestedAA:I
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeRequested32bitDisplayBuffer:Z
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeRender:Z
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeRecreateGfxState:VL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativePause:Z
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeInjectEvent:ZL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeInitWWW:VL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeFocusChanged:VZ
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeFile:VL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeDone:V
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeActivityIndicatorStyle:I
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.initJni:VL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.UnitySendMessage:VLLL
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetLocationStatus:VI
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeSetLocation:VFFFFDF
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeForwardEventsToDalvik:VZ
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.nativeDeviceOrientation:VI
02-06 11:44:57.022: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.fmodUnblockStreaming:I
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.fmodProcess:IL
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.fmodInitJni:I
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.fmodGetInfo:II
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.fmodBlockStreaming:I
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lorg/fmod/FMODAudioDevice;.fmodProcessMicData:ILI
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper;.nativeProxyInvoke:LILL
02-06 11:44:57.030: D/dalvikvm(13604): Unregistering JNI method Lcom/unity3d/player/ReflectionHelper;.nativeProxyFinalize:VI
```

Without proguard all work's successfull.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780902/problem-with-proguard-and-xmlpullparser

Comment: what does that mean? Unity it's XmlPullParser?