# Unable to ignore proguard warning

Tags: proguard, android-proguard, detox

I'm trying to add Detox e2e testing to my project, and when I run the `assembleAndroidTest` I get proguard warnings that fails the build:

`Warning: library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Note: there were 13 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 39 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Warning: there were 89 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 16 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)`

Couldn't find any `dontwarn` that suppressed it and allowed me to build the project, [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333830/android-proguard-error-with-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparser) didn't worked either.

Thanks

Comment: There's data missing here, can you please post which task throws that error ?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: Do you include in your dependencies an `androidTestImplementation` for `com.android.support.test:rules` or `com.android.support.test.espresso`? If you don't rely on them for testing, you can remove those dependencies and I *think* that will resolve the issue.